# Why is the Java download only offered via HTTP, not HTTPS?

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, java

I am looking to get the newest Java package on http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

However, **I can not open that page using https**, which seems to leave open a great opportunity for "drive-by downloads" for MITM's by injecting malicuious content into the download stream, for example. Let alone DNS poisoning.

Even if I could find some MD5 hashes on that site, they could be manipulated.

**Why does Oracle not protect the download of their assets?** Or am I misunderstanding something about secure downloads entirely?

Comment: This sounds more like a rant than like a question

Comment: Ask Oracle, they are the only ones to have your answer.

Comment: Perhaps they are relying on code signing?

Comment: @A.Hersean I have done so to the local office. Waiting for a reply now....

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/s/digest/8u131checksum.html The SHA 256 and MD5  (yuck) are on the download page and that link is https.

Comment: @rjdkolb How are we supposed to find that link from the download page?? Anyway, providing hashes over HTTPS is a good reason to distribute over HTTP only, So if you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: using `CertUtil -hashfile jre-8u131-windows-i586.exe" SHA256 > sha256.txt?` did produce the correct signature. Yay! Gives me the extra comfort I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no excuse for Oracle not serving it's downloads over https, but there are SHA 256 and MD5 (yuck) hashes on the download page. The link is https.

***This does rely on the user downloading the image to check the sha256, which unfortunately few people do.***

When clicking on the 'checksum' link below you will hit a link like this:

https://oracle.com/webfolder/s/digest/8u131checksum.html

[image: 8u131checksum]